# Change variable value from NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, global-variables, nstimer

I'm newbie to Cocoa/Objective C. I've to change a value of a global `NSSTring` variable on every iteration of an `NSTimer` execution. I've declared the variable inside the appdelegate.m at the top of the file so it's global:

```
NSString *my_string = @"hello";
```

I call the `NSTimer`:

```
[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(scan:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] fire];
```

and inside scan i set the new value to `my_string`:

```
- (void) scan:(NSTimer *)timer{
    //some execution
    my_string = @"the new value";
}
```

but the variable value is always the same "hello", the content won't change. 
Is it possible to do this? Solutions?

Comment: It looks like your code should work. Where you are checking and finding the unchanged value?

Comment: on each execution of scan method i check the variable value with a breakpoint or a log and it is always valued to "hello". Instead i want change the variable value my_string persistently to the new one so i can read this from another function in the same .m file.

Comment: I don't think the shown code has any issues. Is it possible to see the whole 'scan' code?

Comment: `- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(scan:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] fire];
}

- (void) scan:(NSTimer *)timer{
    NSString *string_2 = @"value calculated by previous computation";
        
    if(string_2 != my_string){
        my_string = string_2;
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call fire method, the scheduled timer will fire automatically after the specified interval.

Also, set a breakpoint at the scan: method to find out if it is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your my_string variable in the .m file then other files won't be able to see it (you #import the .h files not the .m). Do you do the timer stuff in the same file (appdelegate.m)?

I recommend not having global variables like this as it will often confuse things as the project builds up. You can have it either as an ivar with an accessor, or as static in the @implementation block with a static accessor so that you can have access to a unique instance from anywhere.

You can log the change to make sure it happens or set a breakpoint.

```
- (void) scan:(NSTimer *)timer{
    //some execution
    my_string = @"the new value";
    NSLog(@"Changed my_string to %@", my_string);
}
```

Comment: yes the timer stuff is inside the same .m file. Every time i enter the scan method fired by the timer with a breakpoint i see that the variable my_string is always valued to "hello" and not with the new value.